# Django-taggit - How to filter all tagged objects, repeating them for each tag?

Tags: python, django, tagging

I need to select all the tagged objects so that they are repeated for each tag marked on them.

For example:

```
class Wallet(BaseModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=85, verbose_name="Wallet")
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.code}"
```

Then if I run the following code:

```
wallet_1 = Wallet.objects.create(code=1)
wallet_1.tags.add(*["A", "B"])
wallet_2 = Wallet.objects.create(code=2)
wallet_2.tags.add(*["C"])
```

I need to select all the wallets so that if the wallet_1 has two tags the select should return wallet_1 twice so the result would be a queryset containing:

```
<QuerySet [<Wallet: 1>, <Wallet: 1>, <Wallet: 2>]>
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can annotate the wallets with the tag name, so:

```
from django.db.models import F

Wallet.objects.annotate(
    tag_name=F('tags__name')
)
```

You can filter `Wallet`s that have not tags with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Wallet.objects.filter(
    tags__isnull=False
).annotate(
    tag_name=F('tags__name')
)
```

The `Wallet` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.tag_name` that specifies the tag name. So the `wallet_1` will occur twice each wallet will have a different value for `.tag_name`.

Note that you do not need to use iterable unpacking here, you can simply write:

```
wallet_1 = Wallet.objects.create(code=1)
wallet_1.tags.add('A', 'B')
wallet_2 = Wallet.objects.create(code=2)
wallet_2.tags.add('C')
```

this is basically what the iterable unpacking will do.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I know about unpacking, in my case it was interesting to use it to add a list of tags at once, this example code is not the real code, it was just for example.